# TFS (on premise) build output shown with wrong character-encoding

Tags: node.js, tfs, character-encoding, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We have TFS2015 and build definition that look like following:

[image]

When I trigger the build I get output with wrong character encoding:

```
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ readable-stream@2.1.5 (buffer-shims@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, core-util-is@1.0.2, util-deprecate@1.0.2, process-nextick-args@1.0.7, isarray@1.0.0)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z run-sequence@1.2.2 node_modules\run-sequence     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ chalk@1.1.3 (supports-color@2.0.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0 node_modules\vinyl-source-stream     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ vinyl@0.4.6 (clone-stats@0.0.1, clone@0.2.0)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2722404Z gulp-concat@2.6.0 node_modules\gulp-concat     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2762404Z Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ concat-with-sourcemaps@1.0.4 (source-map@0.5.6)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2762404Z ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2762404Z vinyl-buffer@1.0.0 node_modules\vinyl-buffer     
2016-09-07T11:40:29.2762404Z Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

---

**EDIT**: When I log to the Build Server VM and run npm install from command prompt, I get correct output:

```
run-sequence@1.2.2 node_modules\run-sequence
└── chalk@1.1.3 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, supports-color@2.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)

merge-stream@1.0.0 node_modules\merge-stream
└── readable-stream@2.1.5 (inherits@2.0.3, buffer-shims@1.0.0, string_decoder@0.10.31, process-nextick-args@1.0.7, util-deprecate@1.0.2, core-util-is@1.0.2, isarray@1.0.0)

vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0 node_modules\vinyl-source-stream
├── vinyl@0.4.6 (clone-stats@0.0.1, clone@0.2.0)
└── through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)
```

**DEV-MACHINE ENVIRONMENT:**

> ```
> OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
> Active code page:          437 (both build server and dev machine)
> System Locale:             sk;Slovak
> Node version:              5.10.1
> NPM version:               3.8.5
> ```

**BUILD SERVER ENVIRONMENT**

> ```
> OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
> Active code page:          437 (both build server and dev machine)
> System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
> Node version:              5.10.1
> NPM version:               3.8.5
> ```

TFS Version is 14.102.25423.0 (Update 3), but it resides on another server, where I don't have access. I see only the webportal.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. npm init
2. npm install run-sequence --save-dev
3. push to TFS Git repository
4. create build definition with single step: npm install
5. queue new build

Comment: What's the version of npm?

Comment: OK, after I upgraded NPM to 5.10.1, it started to work. Previously there was installed current LTS release (4.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a gulp imagemin task in my build, but couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. In order to narrow down the issue, please check:

1. Whether the TFS 2015 has upgraded to the latest edition Update 3.
2. Check whether the npm is the latest version on your build server.
3. Manually run gulp task on build agent server to see whether the issue can be reproduced.
4. If the options above not work, please share detailed setting of your build tasks, I'd like to set up a same environment to check whether your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Please see my edit for details. It is not gulp task, but npm install, whose output is incorrectly displayed.

Comment: not 100% sure, but upgrading NPM probably solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that it works when run npm install from command prompt, you can also add a "Command Line" task in your build definition to run the npm install command.
[image]